# Gunicorn: multiple background worker threads

Tags: python, multithreading, gunicorn

**Setup**: My application uses multiple workers to process elements in parallel. Processing those elements is CPU-intensive, so I need worker processes. The application will be used via a Flask API and GUnicorn. GUnicorn itself has multiple worker processes to process requests in parallel. In the Flask API, the request data is put onto a queue and the worker processes of my background application take this data from that queue.

**Problem**: Forking worker processes is quite time intensive and the application has to meet a certain speed requirement. Therefore, I would like to spawn the background worker processes when the app starts. To avoid mixing results, I need `n` background worker processes for every GUnicorn worker.

**Question**: How can I determine during construction time how many background workers I have to spawn and how is it possible to link those workers to GUnicorn workers?

**Approach**: I can read the number of GUnicorn workers from `gunicorn_config.py` by importing the `workers` variable. However, at this point, I do not know the GUnicorn worker process IDs. Do they have internal IDs that I could use at this point (e.g., GUnicorn worker #1, ...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be aware (and account for) that a gunicorn worker can be stopped at any time (for example due to crash of the request hander or timeout in processing). So this means that hardwiring of your particular worker to particular gunicorn process cannot be permanent.

If you want to link your worker to particular gunicorn worker then relinking should happen every time gunicorn worker is restarted.

One approach would be to define your own [post_fork handler](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#post-fork) and/or [port_fork_init](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#post-worker-init) that would do that wiring.

Initially you can start the required number of workers and then `post_fork` handler may "borrow" (or as you call it "link") them to a worker that just have been created.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It looks promising. Does it also make sense to create and start my workers in one of those server hooks and if I'd set them into deamon mode, would those workers stop when the GUnicorn worker crashes for which they were created?